# What is the best way to integrate x32 lib with x64 process(without converting the lib to x64)?

Tags: windows, 64-bit

I inherited a lib that compiled in x32 and I can't compile it to x64.
I think may be to envelop the lib with x32 process and then to run it in x64 process by calling to CreateProcess function win api.
then I will use shared memory for transfert the data between the API lib x32 interfaces to the x64 process.

Do I miss something here(its look very complicated)?

Comment: Does your process really have to have 64-bit?

Comment: yes, I need 3Gbyte memory allocation

Answer (score 3):

They answer is that you cannot do this directly.  Processes are either 32-bit, or 64-bit.   A 64-bit process cannot load a 32-bit code.

Yes, you have to run the 32-bit code in a 32-bit process and use some type of interface between it and your 64-bit process.

Depending on your code, this could be a lot of work.

The best way to do this is likely to wrap your 32-bit code in a set of COM APIs and run it as an our of proc COM server for your 64-bit process.   COM will then do all the work of marshaling information from one process to another.

No matter what you do; be acutely aware that there is a LOT of overhead to do this.  Error handling is another significant concern.

I encourage you not to develop your own shared memory interface.  This can be quite challenging to get corrects unless the interfaces are really simple.

You could also use RPC directly: see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373550%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I think you could expose it as 32bit COM+ server and consume it from 64bit app. It will be separate process hosted by OS. It seems to me much easier than shared memory etc. Just idea, I never tried.